# How to make a Java PlugIn?

Tags: java, plugins, plugin-architecture

I need to make my Java program as a PlugIn to OME - an Image processing web based s/w having Java API

www.openmicroscopy

Comment: What do you want this plugin to do? Do you know Java? Have you downloaded the source to OME? When I looked at the site (it would have been nice for you to give a real URL), I didn't see any defined plugin API docs, so you'll probably have to find your own way to hook into the code.

Answer (score 3):

[OmeroJava](http://trac.openmicroscopy.org.uk/omero/wiki/OmeroJava) is the appropriate API for the latest version of OME (OMERO 4.2), if you are writing a client. If you would like to embed your code inside of Insight (the OMERO Java client), then you should start with [How to write a client](https://trac.openmicroscopy.org.uk/shoola/wiki/OmeroInsightHowToBuildAgent). Other links to [OME-Java libraries](http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/legacy/ome-server/developer/java-api) are for a legacy version and should **not** be used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [Open Microscopy Java API](http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/legacy/ome-server/developer/java-api) is worth investigation. If it's not, it's worth highlighting in your question as to why it's not suitable (marked as legacy?)